# Does anyone have the UIViewAdditions file from WWDC 2009 session 128?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, prototyping

Hopefully without violating any NDA, here is my question: I have been reviewing the WWDC session on prototyping, and I've gotten stuck on whatever we weren't shown that is in the UIViewAdditions file. Can anyone point me in the right direction to find the code from that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the [attendee page for that session](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/attendee/sessions/session.php?id=128) (login required) but no code is posted. If the code mentioned is perchance associated with Three20, [here is a link](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/d8927e69cde4759a46784eeab46e57232de95714/src/UIViewAdditions.m). If not, can you clarify what you know about the file? (Without violating WWDC session NDA, of course — only if the file is publicly available.) What is the general thing you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks Quinn! Both the Three20 link and the fruitsandsoftware link below were very helpful. Basically the session was on rapid prototyping, and the UIViewAdditions file had a bunch of convenience methods to manipulate UIViews quickly, thus making it very fast to protype the interface without having to write too much code.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

http://fruitstandsoftware.com/blog/2009/07/uiview-manipulation-made-easier-with-a-category/

Comment: Thanks for the link! Both of the links provided in answers here were helpful in getting me on the right track.